# Strtok to separate all whitespace

Tags: c, string, strtok

I'm trying to split a string at spaces and tabs.

```
char * token = strtok(input, " \t");
```

works only for spaces. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work for `\t`?

Comment: The code you've shown so far looks correct.  Can you post a larger section of code that demonstrates the unexpected behavior you're seeing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is an example that illustrates that strtok() will work on tabs or spaces.
The key is to pass in NULL on the all but the first call to strtok().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[1024];
    int rv = sprintf(buffer, "a string\ttokenize.");
    char *token = strtok(buffer, " \t");
    int i = 0;
    printf("cnt  token\n");
    printf("==========\n");
    while (token) {
        printf("%2d %s\n", i++, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " \t");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output from above program is as follows below.

```
cnt  token
==========
 0 a
 1 string
 2 tokenize.
```

Comment: This answer is perfect. I know it's a bit late, but I believe there is a type: within the while loop, it should be "*token" instead of "token".

Comment: I do not believe this is the case @marc.soda Token is a string (char array), so de-referencing would only attempt to put the token in the first place in the array. This is not the desired behavior.